# koGrid empties our grid instead of updating with KnockoutJS with Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

We're working on ASP.Net MVC 3 + knockout-2.1.0 and we're trying to render a koGrid but have an Ajax issue (we think) that is emptying the koGrid instead of updating it.

In the initial state, the datasource for the koGrid is an array with two rows, this is the ViewModel (vm):

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.radioSelectedOptionValue = ko.observable('-1');
    self.AvailableActiveProducts = ko.mapping.fromJS(availableActiveProductsObject);
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

AvailableActiveProducts is the datasource for the grid. This is the html:

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: { data: AvailableActiveProducts }" />
```

And the grid renders fine initially:

[image: IMG]

The problem starts here, when the radioSelectedOptionValue changes (it does 
with a radiobutton control change), the grid should be updated, but its emptied.

[image: IMG]

We expect the radiobutton to update/change with a knockout subscribe function call:

```
self.radioSelectedOptionValue.subscribe(function() {
    $.get('/SalesOrderManagement/GetProductsBySelection', { 
        typeCriteria: "g", id: 1, seasonType: "1" }, function(data) {
            self.AvailableActiveProducts(data.AvailableActiveProducts);
        });
    }, this);
```

In the controller, the method that responds to this Ajax call is:

```
public JsonResult GetProductsBySelection(string typeCriteria, long id, string seasonType)
{
    var model = _orchestrator.GetProductsByUserCriteria(typeCriteria, id, seasonType);
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Debugging with fiddler, the json object returns (with 3 rows that we expect) but the grid goes empty after the call.

[image: IMG]

**Our hypothesis is that how the data is set to the observableArray is part the problem.  How can we get this update to render/work properly?**

We think we've found someone else who is suffering with the same issue, but there was no response on the KO list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/knockoutjs/BS4ugQfV14g

Here is a jsFiddle that exhibits the same behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/wabe/H4ZXM/7/

**UPDATE: Solved!**

We noted after Tyrsius' comment that the grid would refresh after several clicks.

So adding a pop and push to force the refresh (per @Keith) makes it all work, the grid updates in the expected way. So javascript chages to:

```
    self.radioSelectedOptionValue.subscribe(function() {
        $.get('/SalesOrderManagement/GetProductsBySelection', { typeCriteria: "gender", id: 1, seasonType: "inseason" }, function(data) {
            self.AvailableActiveProducts(data);
            self.AvailableActiveProducts.push({});
            self.AvailableActiveProducts.pop();
        });

    }, this);
```

The push and pop makes the final update/koGrid refresh.  This is Keith's fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/MYYNw/

Comment: Your json looks like a flat array, so the line `self.AvailableActiveProducts(data.AvailableActiveProducts);` should be `self.AvailableActiveProducts(data);`

Comment: The arrays are updated but the koGrid is not updated.  However, if you do a second refresh, the Ajax event is not fired but the koGrid does manage to update with this second click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like its not properly updating, if you click the top columns to sort, then the data appears....

and if I push and pop a dummy item, the code "looks" to work as you are expecting

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/MYYNw/

note, I took the mapping out, as you don't map your initial data,  either map both, or neither (depending if you want to observe changes on the actual data elements)

Comment: Along with Tyrsius' comment, this put us on the right path and we have updated our question with the evolution of the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: note, this is just a workaround, I think there is a bug in the grid, so I'd go to the github page and raise an issue there.

Comment: Added this as an issue to koGrid's Github page: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/issues/46

Answer (score 1):

I have this exact problem and worked around it by moving the viewModel binding inside the ajax call.

Old & Busted:

```
            var API_URL = "/api/vendor/";

            window.viewModel = {
                items: ko.observableArray([]),
                item: ko.observableArray([])
            }

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

            function getVendors() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: API_URL,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        newData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
                        viewModel.items(newData);
                    }
                });
            };

            getVendors();
```

New Hotness:

```
           var API_URL = "/api/vendor/";
           $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: API_URL,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    window.viewModel = {
                        items: ko.mapping.fromJS(data),
                        item: ko.observableArray([])
                    }
                    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                }
            });
```